# Appcelerator studio not seeing connected android device

Tags: android, appcelerator

I am looking at options for mobile app dev and currently exploring Appcelerator Studio as an option. I have downloaded and installed the software and I am now attempting my first "Hello World" type app. I find running the Android Emulator painfully slow so tried connecting my Samsung phone to my laptop so I could run on that but Appcelerator Studio doesn't see it. When I try to do a configuration the available devices drop down list is always empty. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

So, appcelerator only uses the connection that is to your PC, so if you're not seeing the connection, it's not an appcelerator thing.

Things to check:
- can your computer see the device? Ie, if you browse your available drives, does your phone show up? Can you browse the files on it? Does the OS notify you that the device ID connected? If not, check drivers on Windows and make sure your device is set to behave like a drive. (You can find this in the notification bar when you are connected via USB to the computer)

Once that is working, you know you're connection to the PC is good, now you needs to put the phone into debug mode for appcelerator to see it.

- goto settings and select developer options from the menu. If you don't see 'developer options' click on about, then find the 'build number' line. Could be in about our you may have to click another level deeper, usually labeled 'software'. Now click the build number 7 timbers. That enables developer mode.

Now go back to main settings screen and click developer mode, turn on USB debugging. Your phone should ask you if it should trust the computer you have it hooked up to. Say yes and then try starting appcelerator studio. Now your device should be listed.

Ray

Comment: Hi Ray, Followed your instructions and now works a treat. Much appreciated.